# TinyMCE - get first node

Tags: html, tinymce, figure

In TinyMCE, I added a widget, that outputs quotes. The output contains  as main tag and inside it's  tag with inserted data. 
I am trying to get first inserted (parent) node from TinyMCE, that being figure node. The example below is HTML inside TinyMCE editor.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<figure data-type="rtv-quotes">
<blockquote contenteditable="false">Test quote<footer><a id="link" href="Random Source">Test Author</a></footer></blockquote>
</figure>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see above, with tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode(), I get only blockquote node and not a figure node as I would want. Is there any way that I could figure node?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some simple JavaScript:

First you need to get the body tag itself:

```
var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName('body')
```

...that returns an HTMLCollection object and there would only be one `<body>` tag so you can get the first element of the collection as `theBody[0]`

Next you use the `firstChild` property to locate the first child of the `<body>` tag:

```
theBody[0].firstChild
```

This will return the first child which in your case is the `<figure>` tag.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. However, that does not work in my case. The whole HTML document that I wrote as an example is inside a text editor (textarea) as an output.
So when for example I click on a button that will align content to right side, I will always get firstChild of TinyMCE and not what's inside textarea.

Comment: Without seeing running code nobody can really help you fix this.  Make a running example of this issue at TinyMCE Fiddle  (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/)

Comment: you are right, it's kinda difficult to explain without a example. So here I made an example: [link](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/jjgaab/1)

If you click Insert->Template, there's a simple template that Inserts a simple quote into a editor. When the content is inserted, when you click on inserted item and you will see in the bottom left corner of the editor Figure >> Blockquote. (mce-path). I want that when I click on the inserted item, that I always select first tag, in that case figure. And yes, I need to have a blockquote inside a figure.

Thank you for your help